# Why not use parenthesis on return functions inside functions in Python?

Tags: python, python-decorators

I'm reading [this tutorial](https://realpython.com/blog/python/primer-on-python-decorators/) and under the **Returning Functions** part, there's an example something like below:

```
def parent(n):

    def child1():
        return "Printing from the child1() function."

    def child2():
        return "Printing from the child2() function."

    if n == 10: return child1
    else: return child2
```

The author mentions that the return functions should not have parenthesis in them but without giving any detailed explanation. I believe that it is because if parenthesis are added, then the function will get called and in some way the flow will be lost. But I need some better explanation to get a good understanding.

Comment: `I believe that it is beacause if parenthisis are added, then the function will get called` - You are correct

Comment: Yeah I think it's working that way, but I believe a better explanation will be good for every one especially beginners.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you add parenthesis i.e. `()` to the return function then you will be returning the return-value of that function (i.e. the function gets executed and its result is returned). Otherwise, you are returning a reference to that function that can be re-used. That is,

```
f = parent(1)
f()  # executes child2()
```

Comment: Corrected grammar before voting :)

Answer (score 3):

```
return func()  # returns the result of calling func
return func    # returns func itself, which can be called later
```

Answer (score 0):

We are defining the functions `child1()` & `child2()` and returning the references to these functions outside the nested scope (here, parent). So, every time you call the `parent` function, new instances of `child1` & `child2`.

And we want these references only.That's why there's no parenthesis. If you add parenthesis, then the function will get called.